# Replace row values with column headers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a specific data set which have been pivoted in SQL. Now I wanted to replace the row values with column header name, that too dynamically.

Initial Table

| StudentID | Response | QuestionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | TRUE | Question2 |
| S1 | TRUE | Question3 |
| S2 | TRUE | Question1 |
| S2 | TRUE | Question2 |
| S2 | TRUE | ..QuestionN |

Table after pivot-

| StudentID | Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | ..QuestionN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | NULL | TRUE | TRUE | NULL |
| S2 | TRUE | TRUE | NULL | TRUE |

Output Expected

| StudentID | Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | ..QuestionN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | NULL | Question2 | Question3 | NULL |
| S2 | Question1 | Question2 | NULL | QuestionN |

I used the below code to pivot in the 'Table after pivot' from the 'Initial Table'.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.TopicId) 
            FROM test c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentId, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select StudentId
                    , Response
                    , TopicId
                from test where Response = ''TRUE''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Response)
                for TopicId in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

So can I make changes in the existing query or make a new out the existing one?

Comment: if want to continue with your existing query just change `max(Response)` with `max(TopicId)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with the method you have used. This is just one rason why I dislike the method of creating a delimited list of the columns and injecting that; it really restricts you.

Instead, inject the expressions you need into the query, don't create a delimited list, and you can achieve what you're after. I also move away from the more restrictive `PIVOT` operator, and also use `sys.sp_executesql` as you can't parametrise your query (should it be required in the future).

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT StudentID,' + @CRLF + 
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'     MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = ' + QUOTENAME(YT.QuestionID,'''') + N' AND Response = ''TRUE'' THEN ' + QUOTENAME(YT.QuestionID,'''') + N' END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(YT.QuestionID)
                  FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                  GROUP BY YT.QuestionID
                  ORDER BY YT.QuestionID
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
           N'GROUP BY StudentID' + @CRLF +
           N'ORDER BY StudentID;';

--PRINT @SQL; --YOur Best Friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This is untested, as the markdown tables don't translate well in a copy and paste, and there's no DDL and DML, however, your best friend will help you in the event of any typographical errors I may have made.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot for the answer and the information too. Will keep those in mind.

Comment: Why are we doing CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)?

Comment: [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/why-i-declare-my-carriage-returns-and-line-breaks-in-dynamic-sql/) @noswear